# Justify the list of figures' captions

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, justification

I am using NYU/Harvard phd thesis template and the list of figure captions is not justified.
I need to fix this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the link to the template that I am using :
https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you **need** to fix this?  Are you creating a template for another university?

Comment: No, I do not want to create another template but my figure captions are long and it does not look good at all, also that is a comment that I have received. Anyways I need to justify them... :)

Comment: The easy solution is to use `\caption[short version]{long version}` and not put long captions into the LOF.  You won't have a problem later for violating standards either.

Comment: The file `Dissertate.cls` is a *disaster*. Lots and lots of out-and-out mistakes. Do yourself a big favor and stay away from it.

Comment: Hey @JohnKormylo, with \caption[short version]{long version} , do you mean I have to have two separate captions for each figure or this is a package that I have to add to .cls file? I am new at this. thanks

Comment: All `\caption`s support optional short versions, except things like \subfloat.  Only the long version will appear in the figure and only the short version will appear in the LOF.  But yes, there are two captions, and if you want to confuse people you could have completely unrelated material.